# Running GDAL from a docker container using Python

Tags: python, gdal, docker

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Add unstable repo to allow us to access latest GDAL builds
RUN echo deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update

# Existing binutils causes a dependency conflict, correct version will be installed when GDAL gets intalled
RUN apt-get remove -y binutils

# Install GDAL dependencies
RUN apt-get -t unstable install -y libgdal-dev g++

# Update C env vars so compiler can find gdal
ENV CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
ENV C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal


RUN pip install \
    GDAL==3.0.4

RUN mkdir -p /app/

COPY / /app/

WORKDIR /app/
```

Running a python script with:

```
def colour_relief():
    subprocess.call(['gdaldem', 'color-relief', dem_imput, 
        r'/app/color_relief.txt', 
        colour_relief_output,'-b','1' ])
```

Results in the below error:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdaldem': 'gdaldem'`

I'm unable to get any results from `gdal --version` from the bash command line.

I am looking for the simplest way to run python with gdal from a container.

Original dockerfile is from:
https://github.com/thinkWhere/GDAL-Docker/blob/develop/3.6/Dockerfile

Comment: Have you had a look at the GDAL projects dockerfiles? https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/master/gdal/docker

Comment: Command `gdal --version` does not give results ever. The first part must be some existing gdal program like `gdalinfo --version` or `ogrinfo --version`